# Mimic Twitter/G+ Tagging Functionality in a Textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to do something similar to what twitter and g+ do when "tagging" people in their app. I can't figure out how I can get a modifier character (like `@` or `+`) to bring up the "autocomplete" search like they do in these apps.

I want to use `!` to pull up a list of items from my database and allow the user to just click one of these autocomplete options (or continue typing) and creating a "link" if my user selects one of the autocomplete options. Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't use G+ or Twitter, there is a [control](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview) that at least provides the autocorrect functionality you wish to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory, ie untested, but maybe you could do this by animating a view around the cursor position that populates with an array...triggered by a special character `@` or whatever...and then searches with the string following the character.